# Django: Clean unicode for UrlEncoding

Tags: python, character-encoding

I am trying to take unicode and clean it to be used for URLs.

Examples : **"Bird's Milk" Cake**  OR **Pão com Ovo**

In converting these, my goal is to make them as human readable as possible so, the urls following those examples would be - `/birds-milk-cake/` or `/pao-com-ovo/`

To get the ASCII of the accented characters,

```
title = 'Pão com Ovo'
title = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', title).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

However I am wondering what the best solution is for removing characters like # ! ' " ( ) &. Normalize() errors on those characters so is there a proper way for removing those characters while retaining the accented characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
>>> slugify("Pão com Ovo")
u'pao-com-ovo'
>>> slugify(""""Bird's Milk" Cake""")
u'birds-milk-cake'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an old, unmaintained but working code that extends [django.template.defaultfilters.slugify()](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaultfilters.py) by adding support for all characters you can imagine. If you need to support all kinds of languages then this may be a good solution. It's called [slughifi](http://www.google.ch/search?q=slughifi).